# Manipulate HTML Elements without runat="server"

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, webforms, runatserver

Take a look at this; right now, it's just wishful thinking.

**Default.aspx**

```
<ul id="menuemenue" runat="server">
    <li><a href="www.google.com">google</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.yahooo.com">yahooo</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
    foreach (var item in menu.Elements("a"))
    {
        if (item.Attribute("href") == currentPageUrl)
        {
            item.addClass("selected");
        }
    }
```

I know I can make this happen by writing my own little HTML engine (or whatever you wanna call it) and manipulate `menu.innerHtml`.  But do i have an alternative?

**Update**

I know it can be done with javascript/jquery, and in a 100 of different ways. But imagine if you could do it like in my example, how clean your c# code would be.

Comment: are you just wanting to apply CSS to it ?

Comment: Well in this example i want to give it a class yes. But it's more about the concept of manipulating HTML elements with no runat="server" attribute.

Comment: Do you have to do it server side ?

Comment: I like to keep my aspx files as clean as possible :)

Comment: What about a javascript include ? (keeps it clean) :)

Comment: If you aren't doing it server side you are at the mercy of what the client allows (ie, javascript will only work if javascript is enabled).

Comment: Yes, there are many ways of achieving that effect. I know it can be done with javascript/jquery aswell, but i really want to be able to do it like that.

Comment: I have to ask, why can't you just add `runat="server"` to all the list items?

Comment: Why isn't runat="server" clean, out of curiosity?

Comment: Why not create a function that prints the entire menu in a loop?  Then you can do your check to see if it is the current page and add the class in the loop.

Comment: @Christian Hayter - you loop through them then?

Comment: how would the c# code look if all of the a tags had runat="server" ?

Comment: `foreach (var item in menuemenue.Controls)`

Comment: Sounds like you want to be giving ASP.NET MVC a look.

Comment: haha ;) I also prefer MVC over web forms, and use it for everything, except in my class where we study for web-forms. I actually got the above code working now, now it is just about makeing it better with more functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could just apply server-tags `<%=[...]%>` which would look something like this:

```
<li><a href="www.google.com" class='<%=1==1?"selected":""%>'>google</a></li>
```

Other than that I'm afraid you might be out of luck if you want to do it via codebehind only.

Comment: Okay, i guess i need to write the necessary code myselvf then :/
Think anyone would be interrested in it when i'm done? or am i a freak wanting to do it that way?